# Why does Google ReCaptcha API allow bad secret key and/or bad user token response?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha

Take a look at the code below. This is server-side. I call the Google ReCaptcha API with bad secret key and bad user token response, as you can see. You know what? It works! More precisely: Google ReCaptcha API doesn't answer with exception (*i.e.:* my `catch` isn't reached). Why? This is not the expected behavior, right?

```
/**
 * Verifies a Recaptcha filled by the user in his Android app.
 * 1. Success: returns the JSON response
 * 2. Failure: throws the error
 **/
exports.verifyRecaptcha = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const user_response_token = data.userResponseToken;
    if(user_response_token === null || user_response_token === '') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with an adequat user response token.');
    }

    const remote_url = 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    const secret = '<MY_REAL_SECRET_KEY>';  // Original value: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  #  Moises' value: https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: remote_url,
        body: {secret: 'Foo', response: 'Bar'},
        // body: {secret: secret, response: user_response_token},
        json: true
    };

    return rp(options)
            .then(parsedBody => {
                return {code: 'Success', message: 'You are actually a human (this msg is for test purposes).'};
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error);
            });
});
```

And below is the Android app code:

```
final SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response = task.getResult();
assert response != null;
final String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
    final HashMap<String, String> the_data = new HashMap<>();
    the_data.put("userResponseToken", userResponseToken);
    FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
            .getHttpsCallable("verifyRecaptcha")
            .call(the_data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void then(@NonNull final Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                    if(context.isDestroyed() || context.isFinishing()) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                            FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                            System.out.println(ffe.getMessage());
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    callback.onAsking();
                    return null;
                }
            });
} else {
    callback.onFailureUserResponseTokenIsEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#error_code_reference) suggest that errors such as `invalid-input-secret`/`invalid-input-response` will appear in the `error-codes` field of the response.

This information doesn't necessarily need to be translated into an HTTP error code (which would cause your `catch` block to execute); in this instance, Google apparently wanted to support multiple simultaneous error messages, and the HTTP response code pertains more to the conduct of the protocol at the HTTP level.

While we're looking at the docs, I should point out that you probably want to refer to the `success` field before presuming that your user is a human.

Comment: So what you recommend me is to not send an HTTP error to the Android app if a bad secret key, *e.g.*, is written? And yes thank you, I've written it but forgot to indicate it in the OP

Comment: If I were you, I'd `throw` if you got a `invalid-input-secret`, to let the client know that the server is having problems. Meanwhile, you should probably also log the event internally, and have the server email a site administrator, to let them know about the problem. Because if your own server is sending the wrong secret, then you need to know about that. But if you get a `invalid-input-response`, that's up to you; You can either assume the client is malfunctioning, or assume the client is malicious. Either way, you're probably not going to allow access.

Comment: If I return this JSON object instead of throwing an exception, it's good or no? `.then(parsedBody => {
    if(!parsedBody.success) {
     return {code: -1};
    }
    return {code: 0};
   })`

Comment: Well, it's mostly a matter of taste. Whatever works best/is most elegant for your framework; whatever your client understands. You don't have to tell the client he's not a human, if you don't want to; legitimate recaptchas won't generate a `userResponseToken` unless they pass, so sending one that illegitimate is a pretty aggressive hacking behavior, IMHO...